# What are my number of expected wins for a multi-entry, multi-win raffle?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Scenario:

There is a raffle with 1000 prizes. I own 40 tickets. I am allowed to win multiple times, but each ticket can only win one time (after first win, I will have 39 tickets, after second win, 38, etc.) Total prizes will go down by 1 after every draw regardless of a win or loss.

Edit: Forgot to add there are 250 tickets total. So 210 other tickets besides my 40.

Example:
Draw 1 - Win: No, Tickets left: 40, Prizes left: 999
Draw 2 - Win: No, Tickets left: 40, Prizes left: 998
Draw 3 - Win: Yes, Tickets left: 39, Prizes left: 997

What is my expected number of "wins" or prizes in this scenario?

Comment: You need to know how many other tickets besides your 40 there are. Work out the problem when there are 10 prizes and you have 3 tickets and there are either 17 or 997 other tickets to see that.

Comment: @EthanBolker sorry, there are 250 tickets total. So 210 other tickets

Comment: $250$ tickets and $1000$ prizes, and at most one prize per ticket...How does that work?